# How to generate random numbers from a known density function in R?

Tags: r, probability

We all know how to generate random numbers from popular distributions in R. Like runif,rnorm,...

I want to know how can I generate a random number from a distribution which I know it has the density function as follows:

fX(x) = 2x for 0 < x < 1

Comment: whenever possible, if you have the closed form for the cumulative distribution, invert that & plug in uniform numbers. Here the CDF is x^2, the inverse is sqrt(u). See `plot(density(sqrt(runif(1e6))))`

Comment: That's a beta density, so you could use `rbeta(n, 2, 1)`.